# Como agrupadr datos de un campo en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen dia, En mi consulta sql tengo 2 datos found y total, en el found mando las eps que tienen mayor a 40 trabajadores y a lo menores de 40 les puse otros, lo que necesito hacer es sumar todos los que dicen otros y esta suma agruparla en "otros"

```
Esta es mi consulta
SELECT fund, total
FROM (
        (
            SELECT  pr_employees.eps_id, pr_funds.fund, COUNT(*) AS total, count(*) AS visible
            FROM pr_employees
            INNER JOIN pr_funds ON pr_funds.id = pr_employees.eps_id
            WHERE pr_employees.status = 1
            GROUP BY pr_employees.eps_id
            HAVING visible > 40
            ORDER BY total ASC
        )
        UNION ALL
        (
            SELECT  pr_employees.eps_id, 'OTROS' AS fund, COUNT(*) AS total, count(*) AS visible
            FROM pr_employees
            INNER JOIN pr_funds ON pr_funds.id = pr_employees.eps_id
            WHERE pr_employees.status = 1
            GROUP BY pr_employees.eps_id
            HAVING visible < 40
            ORDER BY total ASC
        )
) AS afp
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Este es el resultado de mi consulta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad no necesitas la columna eps_id ni visible.

Lo que puedes hacer es realizar primero el cálculo del total de empleados por `fund`, luego sustituir el nombre del `fund` a `'OTROS'` para aquellos que tengan menos de 40 empleados y finalmente agrupar por `fund`. Con esto en mente, puedes simplificar tu consulta a algo como esto:

Ojo, que con tu consulta original, si un `fund` tiene exactamente 40 empleados, este no aparecería en los resultados de la consulta, pero con la propuesta en esta respuesta si aparecería. He hecho eso suponiendo que la has excluido por error.

```
select fund, sum(total) total
  from (select   case when total >= 40 then fund else 'OTROS' end fund
               , total
          from (select pr_funds.fund, count(*) AS total
                 from pr_employees
                      inner join pr_funds ON pr_funds.id = pr_employees.eps_id
                where pr_employees.status = 1
                group by pr_employees.eps_id
               ) q1
       ) as afp
 group by fund
 order by sum(total) desc
```

Comment: Amigo con esta consulta solo me agrupa los datos, y hace el count, solo me sale un registro no mas

Comment: Originalmente había omitido un `group by`, asegurate de copiar el texto actual y probarla. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue de mucha ayuda ayuda!!